# react codesandbox different behaviour input does not lose focus

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello I have created a sandbox with a react table.
How ever in the codesandbox everything works fine.
When I copy the same code to my create-react-app application.
The Input loses focus after typing one character.
The versions of the npm packages are the same.
Can somebody explain me this?
Why does it work in codesandbox? And why does this dont work with create-react-app?
Here is the codesandbox: [Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-counter-demo-ojfvp?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: I got same problem now. Guy open this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59715158/react-hooks-input-loses-focus-when-1-character-is-typed-in I just copied it in sendbox and it works perfectly.

I have same issue in big app, and wanted to create small working example in sendbox to test it, but it seams all works flawlessly in sendbox, input do not lose focus when I expect it. :)

Did you find any solution, or article about losing focus?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without viewing your create-react-app code, but it's most likely because you put your `MyDataTable` component inside your `App` component when copying it over, like with these issues:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/62822593/5325737
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/49688084/5325737

Comment: My create react app is exactly the same... I will look tomorrow